# Different adapter in items of recyclerview

Tags: android

I am creating a list which contains, different types of views. **Like facebook does in showing their feeds** in Mobile Application. 
**Example**  Some times scrollview or some times list inside list.

To do this what will be a good choice. 
What if i add a fragment in each item of recyclerview. Like

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:name="com.profile.EditProfileFragment"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

and add this as a item in Reclycleview and keep different logic inside it.

Can any one suggest me how to go through this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's going to be possible using Fragment as a row. Fragment has its own lifecycle which I don't lies within what RecyclerView can control. 
But you can do it with simple view.

Just override several methods in RecyclerView.Adapter

```
private ArrayList<Data> items = new ArrayList<>(); // data associated 
// with each row

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return items.get(position).getRowType(); 
// assuming this is the getter to get the type
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    switch (viewType) {
        case Data.TYPE_A:
            View convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.row_feed, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolderTypeA(convertView);
        case Data.TYPE_B:
        ...
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Data data = items.get(position);

    if (holder instanceof ViewHolderTypeA) {
        ViewHolderTypeA holderA= (ViewHolderTypeA) holder;
        // manipulate the views in view holder for this type
         ...
    }else if (holder instanceof ViewHolderTypeB){

    }
}
```

Edit: You don't need different Adapter for each item. You just need item that includes all your logic. So if you want to have two row types, one for status, one for photo like Facebook feed then your item will be:

```
class Data {
    String status, photoUrl;
}
```

Of course some members will be empty depending on the row.

Comment: I know this and used also However if i want to add a different logic for each item then.  means i have to add a adapter for each item.